# BCC LD86 file has bad magic number

Tags: compilers

I wanted to write a simple hello world program in DOSBox, so I downloaded Bruce's C Compiler from [here](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/micro/pc-stuff/freedos/files/distributions/1.2/repos/pkg-html/bcc.html). And wrote this program (using `edit.exe`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I ran bcc like this: `bcc -o hello hello.c`, but I get this error every time:

```
C:\BCC\DEVEL\BCC\BIN\LD86.EXE: HELLO.C has bad magic number
```

I tried `bcc hello.c -o hello.exe` and got the same error.

I don't know why this is happening, if anyone can tell me please do.

I'm running DOSBox 0.74 on 64-bit Windows 10.

EDIT: I ran bcc with filenames in all uppercase (as what you would get from autocomplete), but if you type it out in lowercase the compiler seems to work just fine.

Comment: Weird, it works for me... What version of DOSBox are you using? On what platform? (BTW, you should run `bcc -o hello.exe hello.c` instead, if you want to be able to run the program without renaming it first.)

Comment: HELLO.C shouldn't have a magic number at all. Did you create it in an editor that saves in Unicode format, or adds text formatting, or something similar, instead of writing plain ASCII text?

Comment: What happens if you try `bcc /o hello hello.c`?

Comment: @DrSheldon BCC only uses Unix-style short flags.

Comment: @DrSheldon “LD86.EXE: cannot open input file /o” ;-)

Comment: Since the error comes from ```LD86```, it looks like the source file is somehow not being recognized as C text but is instead being passed to the loader.  @alephzero has provided possible causes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has to do with the way `bcc` handles file extensions. First, a note: code in this answer may be *slightly* modified from the original (for simplicity, readability and to aid understanding), but the basic idea is preserved. Having said that, let's begin the analysis.

---

In `bcc.c`, the file names on the command line (i.e., all those arguments not starting with `-`) are parsed in `getargs`, called from `main`:

```
for(ar=1; ar<argc; )
    if (argv[ar][0] != '-') {
        append_file(argv[ar++], 0);
        file_count++;
    } else ...
```

You can see that `append_file` is being called with `0` as the second argument for each of the files. Following the code down to there (still in `bcc.c`), we see what happens when this is the case:

```
void append_file (char *filename, int ftype) {
   struct file_list *newfile = xalloc(sizeof(struct file_list));
   char *s, *name;

   newfile->file = copystr(filename); name = copystr(filename);

   char *s = strrchr(name, '.');
   if (ftype) {
      newfile->name = copystr(name); newfile->filetype = ftype;
   } else if (s && s == name + strlen(name) - 2) {
      newfile->filetype = s[1]; *s = 0; newfile->name = copystr(name);
   } else ...
```

Since `ftype` is zero, it skips the first `if` block and enters the `else if` block (it finds the `.<extension>` exactly two characters before the string terminator, meaning `<extension>` is a single character).

So it simply stores the character *as-is,* in all its case-sensitive glory:

```
  newfile->filetype = s[1];
```

If you then look back in the `main` function, you'll find it acts on the file extension, performing specific actions:

```
for (next_file = <all-files>) {
    if (next_file->filetype == 'o') continue;

    /* Assembler that's not to be optimised. */
    if (do_preproc && next_file->filetype == 'x') run_aspreproc(next_file);
    if (do_preproc && next_file->filetype == 'S') run_aspreproc(next_file);
    if (do_as      && next_file->filetype == 's') run_as(next_file);

    /* C source */
    if (do_preproc && next_file->filetype == 'c') run_preproc(next_file);
    if (do_unproto && next_file->filetype == 'i') run_unproto(next_file);
    if (do_compile && next_file->filetype == 'i') run_compile(next_file);
    if (do_optim   && next_file->filetype == 's') run_optim(next_file);
    if (do_as      && next_file->filetype == 's') run_as(next_file);
}

if (do_link && !error_count)
    run_link();
```

Note that first line following the "C source" comment, it checks for *lower-case* `c` only.

Each `run_<phase>` function is responsible for removing the original file from the list and adding a newly generated file. For example, `x.c` may be turned into `x.i`, the original file removed from the list and the generated file added.

However, `run_preproc` is *only* being called for any file with a *lower-case* `c` extension. Indeed, *no* `run_<phase>` function gets called for the upper-case variant of `C`, meaning that file is left in the file list for the linker.

---

So, in short:

- the extension is identified as upper-case `C`;
- this is not considered a C file (or *any* type of file the compiler can handle) by the file type detector in `main`;
- it is therefore be left in the file list to be passed to the linker for resolution.

Then, of course, the linker has *no* idea what to do with a C source file so it rightly complains bitterly - the magic it's looking for is almost certainly the header at the start of an object or library file, neither of which the C source file contains.

And, in fact, this is further supported by the fact you *can* use an upper-case source file, just not for the extension bit:

```
C:\SRC> BCC -O HELLO.EXE HELLO.C
C:\BCCBIN\LD86.EXE: HELLO.C has bad magic number

C:\SRC> BCC -O HELLO.EXE HELLO.c
C:\SRC> hello
Hello, World!
```

---

One way to *fix* this would be to just treat upper-case `C` as a valid extension for C source code as well, something like:

```
if (do_preproc && tolower(next_file->filetype) == 'c') run_preproc(next_file);
```

Comment: Thank you for the analysis, I figured out that I need to pass lowercase filenames, but didn't understand why.

Comment: As a bit of context, it's probably following the old convention (which [GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45929134/435253) and Vim (tested it myself) also follow) that `.c` and `.h` are C source code, but `.C` and `.H` are C++ source code.